# How to not write dumb overloads but handle lots of casting in overloaded function

Tags: c#, casting, overloading

I would like to design something that gets the distance between two things. However, these things can be manifest in many obnoxious forms.

Let's say we have a set of classes. (Not necessarily base and derived)
Cat, CoolCat, ReallyCoolCat

All of them have a way to access a position. I would like to write a function call 'DistanceBetween' that gets the distances between the cats.

I can make overloads:

```
public static float DistanceBetween(Cat cat1, Cat cat2)
{
    return Mathf.Abs(cat1.position - cat2.position);
}

public static float DistanceBetween(CoolCat cat1, CoolCat cat2)
{
    return Mathf.Abs(cat1.transform.position, cat2.transform.position);
}

// ... etc...
```

However, then I would have cases where I need to know the distance between a Cat and a CoolCat or the distance between a CoolCat and a ReallyCoolCat. That means...

```
public static float DistanceBetween(Cat cat1, CoolCat cat2)
{
    return Mathf.Abs(cat1.position, cat2.transform.position);
}

public static float DistanceBetween(CoolCat cat1, ReallyCoolCat cat2)
{
    return Math.Abs(cat1.tranform.position, cat2.kittyVariables.position);
}

// ... etc ...
```

But then it just seems arbitrary cause I can rearrange the order of my arguments and my function wouldn't work. So I have to make...

```
public static float DistanceBetween(CoolCat cat1, Cat cat2)
{
    return Mathf.Abs(cat1.tranform.position, cat1.position);
}

public static float DistanceBetween(ReallyCoolCat cat1, CoolCat cat2)
{
    return Math.Abs(cat1.kittyVariables.position, cat2.transform.position);
}

// ... etc ...
```

So This means the amount of code per cute kitties I make grows by n^2. This amount of code growth is not acceptable due to how many cute kitties I want to make. I cannot implement inheritance because my cute kitties (though similar in name) have very different features and are unique. (I could add doggies and the such too.) So what I am thinking is to create an interface 'IDistanceable' that says the implementing class has a 'Position' property and implementing it in each kitty. But this starts to seem like overkill though, all I wanted was something that can rearrange my arguments and make Func(a,b) equal to Func(b,a)...

I don't really know what to do... both solutions (write 500 functions or make interface and lots of junk) both seem wrong.

The interface will NOT work due to the inability to modify some of the cute kitty classes...

Please help me and my cute kitties! Thanks!

Comment: If they all have a way to access a position, make an interface called `IPositioned` and make them implement it.  Then you only need a `GetDistance` function that takes 2 `IPositioned` objects.  This is *exactly* what Interfaces are for.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that with the 'IDistanceable' interface... Now I realize something though. Some of the cute kitties are classes I cannot modify.

Comment: Absolute worst case, make the `GetDistance` function take 2 objects, and use reflection to look for a `Position` property.  If the "position" function is named differently in some classes, you may need to use special logic to find the right function.  It would also be possible to use `dynamic` objects.

Comment: Then you can make an overload for those classes you cannot modify and use an interface for the rest. Do all these clases share some base class?

Comment: That sounds really hard. But is there a way to just make Func(a,b) equal to Func(b,a) so that the growth of code can be reduced from n^2 to the nth triangle number

Comment: @Andrew, No because all the cats are unique

Comment: I'm a little curious as to what situation is giving you a multitude of "cat" classes that doesn't allow you to control the class definition.  It seems like an odd framework.

Comment: I've got an idea for another option that uses `Expression` and lambdas to do some object conversion.  Give me a few minutes to type it up.

Comment: As you were curious, I am developing a video game with Unity and want to be able to have a distance between function that accepts everything from transforms to Vector3's to custom defined classes (that contain a representation of a position). Some of the stuff is ingrained into Unity and I have no access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't modify the classes, you're best off wrapping them in something you can modify. That way, you can centralize the class-specific logic in one place (the different constructors).

```
class CatWrapper
{
    private int position { get; set; }

    public CatWrapper(Cat cat) { ... }
    public CatWrapper(CoolCat cat) { ... }
    public CatWrapper(ReallyCoolCat cat) { ... }

    public DistanceFrom(CatWrapper other) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I like this. You should consider making the wrapper implement 
 an `IPositioned` interface though, that way only one `GetDistance` function will be required, and only special-case objects need to be wrapped.  BTW, this pattern has a name, it is called the "[Adapter](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern)" pattern.

Comment: Wow, this is super cool! I like this too. But just out of curiosity, at how many cats would you just brute force overload and at how many will you use this cool design pattern? I'm kind of new and bad at coding so I kind of want some of your guys' common sense.

Comment: If you control the class, it should directly implement the interface.  If you don't control, use the wrapper.  That's the way that involves the least amount of code.

Comment: "at how many cats would you just brute force overload and at how many will you use this cool design pattern?" There's two variables here: how many classes and how many properties. If you need to work with `position` and `velocity`, then you'll have to make twice as many overloads. My rule of thumb would be at three or more overloads, switch to a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

This is a purely academic answer, since @Andrews Pilser's is far superior for almost any real-world project, but this will solve it for *any* class that has *any* conceivable way of representing a location.  It makes heavy use of lambda-expressions, and generics, and requires no control over the underlying classes.

The code was written in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), so it may look a little odd, but it is standard C# (version 7) that can be snapped right in to Visual Studio. File available [here](http://share.linqpad.net/23r3tl.linq).

This uses a `Dictionary` to store a `ToPointConverter` for any `Type` that can be converted to a `Point`. A `ToPointConverter` is created from a static method `Create` that accepts a lambda that returns a `Point` from the specific generic `T`.

As you can see, I provide 3 example "kitty" classes that each store their location in completely different ways. The main function creates a converter for each, storing it in the dictionary of converters, and then calculates the distance between the different combination of "kitties". (I may have gotten my distance function wrong, it's late, but that is a minor detail.)

It produces this output:

> 2.23606797749979
>   9.05538513813742
>   2.23606797749979
>   8.06225774829855
>   9.05538513813742
>   8.06225774829855

```
void Main()
{
    //Define conversion functions for anything that can be converted.
    converters.Add(typeof(KittyA), ToPointConverter<KittyA>.Create(kitty => kitty.Location));
    converters.Add(typeof(KittyB), ToPointConverter<KittyB>.Create(kitty => new Point { X = kitty.X, Y = kitty.Y }));
    converters.Add(typeof(KittyC), ToPointConverter<KittyC>.Create(kitty => kitty.MyLocation));

    //Declare some kitties
    var kitty1 = new KittyA { Location = new Point { X = 1, Y = 1 } };
    var kitty2 = new KittyB { X = 3, Y = 2 };
    var kitty3 = new KittyC { MyLocation = new Point { X = 2, Y = 10 } };

    //Calculate the distances
    GetDistance(kitty1, kitty2).Dump();
    GetDistance(kitty1, kitty3).Dump();

    GetDistance(kitty2, kitty1).Dump();
    GetDistance(kitty2, kitty3).Dump();

    GetDistance(kitty3, kitty1).Dump();
    GetDistance(kitty3, kitty2).Dump();
}
private Dictionary<Type, IToPointConverter> converters = new Dictionary<Type, IToPointConverter>();

//A helper function that does the converts the passed objects in to Points, and calculates the distance between them.
private double GetDistance(object obj1, object obj2)
{
    var point1 = GetConvrterFor(obj1).Convert(obj1);
    var point2 = GetConvrterFor(obj2).Convert(obj2);

    return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point2.X - point1.X, 2) + Math.Pow(point2.Y - point1.Y, 2));
}

//Another helper that gets the IToPointConverter for the object instance passed in.
private IToPointConverter GetConvrterFor(object obj) => converters[obj.GetType()];

//This generic class stores a lambda expression that converters from T to a Point
public class ToPointConverter<T> : IToPointConverter
{
    public static ToPointConverter<T> Create(Func<T, Point> conversion)
    {
        return new ToPointConverter<T>(conversion);
    }

    private ToPointConverter(Func<T, Point> conversion)
    {
        _conversion = conversion;
    }

    private Func<T, Point> _conversion;

    public Point Convert(T obj) => _conversion(obj);

    Point IToPointConverter.Convert(object obj) => Convert((T)obj);
}

//The non-generic interface for the converter (so different closed generic types can be stored in the same dictionary, and have their Convert method called.)
public interface IToPointConverter
{
    Point Convert(object obj);
}

//Just a standard structure to hold a location.  You would use whatever native location class your framework has.
public struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}


//Some example kitty classes
public class KittyA
{
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}

public class KittyB
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

public class KittyC
{
    public Point MyLocation { get; set; }
}
```